# How to get non-instantiated prefab from script by tag in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I used this line to find all prefabs by tag (this is important, so for example I can just create a whole new ground platform, and it will automatically appear in the script, and won't have to put it in manually)

```
ObjectPool[] platformPools;
float[] platformWidths;

 void Start()
{
    var taggedObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().Where(g => g.CompareTag("Prefabs")).ToArray();

    platformPools = new ObjectPool[taggedObjects.Length];

    platformWidths = new float[platformPools.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < platformPools.Length; i++)
    {
        platformPools[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<ObjectPool>();
        platformPools[i].PooledObject = taggedObjects[i];
        platformWidths[i] = platformPools[i].PooledObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, this script finds every platform while debugging on computer, but as soon as I load it on my phone, it only finds one of them.

Comment: If they are not referenced anywhere they might get stripped off in a build. Rather drag them in via the Inspector or if you want to be sure you would need to put them all into the Resources folder ... but before you do that read the [Best Practices for the Resources System](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) which clearly states: ***`Don't use it.`***

Comment: If you don't want to reference them manually you could do it in one single click: `[SerializedField] private List<GameObject> taggedObjects;` then have a context menu method `[ContextMenu(nameof(GetTaggedPrefabs))] private void GetTaggedPrefabs() { taggedObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)).Cast<GameObject>().Where(g => g.CompareTag("Prefabs")).ToArray(); }` Now you can go to the Inspector of this component, open the context menu and click `GetTaggedPrefabs`